# How to modify a models who's already migrated in Database?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I am new to django, I want to modify my models (Which is already in my sqlite3 database) without bugging my entire project. Last time I modified my models it took me hours to fix it cause I bugged the whole project. So I dont want to make the same error, could you guys help me witht the commands please? Thanks for helping

models.py (at the moment)

```
from django.db import models

THE_GENDER = [
    ("Monsieur", "Monsieur"),
    ("Madame", "Madame")
]


class Post(models.Model):


    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=THE_GENDER)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The edit that I want to make to the models (I want to add an author user into the models. So i know whos making the form.)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

THE_GENDER = [
    ("Monsieur", "Monsieur"),
    ("Madame", "Madame")
]


class Post(models.Model):


    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=THE_GENDER)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my admin.py files (not sure If ill need to leave it the same or modify it)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

my forms.py files

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper


class post_form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(post_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["name", "email", "gender", "number"]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import post_form


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    form = post_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
        "form": form
    }


    return render(request, "sms/home.html", context)
```

Comment: if you haven't created any posts yet, you can go ahead and add the author, also you don't need to change anything in the admin

Comment: Can you add your views.py as well?

Comment: @Bernard'BetaBerlin'Parah I made two post. Can I go to the admin page and delete both and than add the author or it will bug the project?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes, I added the views,py

Comment: wait, don't do anything yet. I will show you the best way to handle this incase you ever encounter it

Comment: @Bernard'BetaBerlin'Parah great im waiting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above...

Adding a new non-nullable ForeignKey in Django is generally a three-step process.

1. First, you add the new ForeignKey to your model definition with `null=True`, and run `makemigrations`. This will create a migration that will add the field, nothing special about it. Executing this migration will add a column with all rows having `NULL` as the value.
2. Second, you create a new empty migration for the same app (`makemigrations --empty`), then edit that migration to contain a *data migration* step. This is where you'll need to, according to your business logic, choose some value for the new foreign key.
3. Third, you modify the ForeignKey in your model definition to set `null=False` and create a third migration with `makemigrations`. Django will ask whether you've dealt with `null`s somehow – you need to say that "yep, I swear I have" (since you did, above in step 2).

In practice, for a simplified version of OP's question where we'll want to add an User foreign key:

### Original state

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

### 1a. Add nullable field.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE))
```

### 1b. Run makemigrations.

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'something':
  something/migrations/0002_post_author.py
    - Add field author to post
```

### 2a. Create a new empty migration.

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations something --empty -n assign_author
Migrations for 'something':
  something/migrations/0003_assign_author.py
```

### 2b. Edit the migration file.

More information on data migrations can be found, as always, [in the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

```py
from django.db import migrations


def assign_author(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User')  # or whatever is your User model
    Post = apps.get_model('something', 'Post')  # or wherever your Post model is
    user = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).first()  # Choose some user...
    assert user  # ... and ensure it exists...
    Post.objects.all().update(author=user)  # and bulk update all posts.


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [...]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(assign_author, migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

### 3a. Make the field non-nullable.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE))
```

### 3b. Run Makemigrations.

Answer truthfully to the question – you've just added a RunPython operation.

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations something -n post_author_non_null
You are trying to change the nullable field 'author' on something. to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
 3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 2
Migrations for 'something':
  something/migrations/0004_post_author_non_null.py
    - Alter field author on post
```

### All done!

Running `migrate` will now run these three migrations and your model will have `author` without data loss.

Comment: I love this method too

Comment: Thansk you a lot for the clear explination. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to edit your `models.py`

```
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=THE_GENDER)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # add new field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Since you added new field **`author`**, you have to run [**`makemigrations`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) command and then the [**`migrate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) command.
During migrations, you may be asked to provide a default value for **`author`** field for ***existing `Post` instances***. In that time, you can **"interactively" provide values via Django shell**. Any valid **`PK`** of **`User`** instances will be a valid input during the time. **FYI:** This is a onetime process

After that, change your **`home(...)`** view as,

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def home(request):
    form = post_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.auther = request.user
        instance.save()

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "sms/home.html", context)
```

**Note:** You should use [**`@login_required(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator to get the ***authenticated user*** in **`request.user`** attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ill check it out in a couples of minutes

Comment: This does not take into account the migration needing a default value for `author`...

Comment: If i run this command on the manage.py shell after I made the migrations ```post_1 = Post(name="oliver", email="oliver@gmail.com", gender="Monsieur", author=user)``` Would it work fine?

Comment: @tiberhockey You will be asked to give a default value for **existing rows**. In that time you can provide ***any valid `PK's` of existing `User' instance`***.

Comment: @AKX I have updated the answer :) I hope it conveys info.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Choosing an arbitrary PK is not a bullet-proof method when you have different databases in your local development copy and a production database where the PK may not exist or may point to another row altogether.

Comment: @AKX Yeah... it's a valid point. So, what do you suggest here? providing a **`null=True`** option?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu See my answer – bullet-proof and production-proven. :)

Comment: @AKX Cool. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Your migration is tricky, because you want every Post related to a user. To workaround this you can do the following:

Add your new field with `null=True`
`models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`
then `manage.py makemigrations`
then you have to decide what to do. Either (1) add authors to your existing posts by hand, or (2) delete them all

```
manage.py shell
from x.models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# 1
user = User.objects.get(id=1) # get your user
Post.objects.all().update(author=user)

# or 2
Post.objects.all().delete()
```

then you can finally set your authors like you want them:
`models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
again `manage.py makemigrations`

See the comments for more information

Comment: No, deleting data is never the right option. Instead, for migrations that need to add a foreign key, the correct method is to add the FK as nullable, then add a data migration (`migrations.RunPython`/`migrations.RunSQL`) that figures out a suitable value, then remove `null=True` off the FK and generate a migration again.

Comment: @AKX what about the method of Arakkal Abu?

Comment: yes you are right, i've added a disclaimer. I still do not understand what happens if you remove `null=True`. Won't you be in the same problem like before?

Comment: @ChrisRob No – `makemigrations` asks whether you've already dealt with NULLs. If you haven't, though, then your RDBMS will complain about it and that migration will fail.

Comment: @ChrisRob I added an answer that shows the steps, including the data migration that doesn't require manual shell intervention.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this issue in different ways.

If there is no data, you can easily add the new field and run your migrations. You should be fine

If you already have posts, you can allow the field to be nullable, then run your migrations before going to populate it.

A more intuitive way of doing this especially if you already have data is to assign a user to the post while running the migrations.

First create a migration with the author field allowed to be null, then

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate

after that, remove the `null` attribute.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`manage.py makemigrations`

open the migration file now generated which will be which you will modify with a custom method like below and run migrate after that.

```
from django.db import migrations, models


# create custom method
def add_author(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User')  
    Post = apps.get_model('something', 'Post')  
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    author = User.object.get(id=1) # whichever user you want to use as the author
    for post in posts:
        post.author = author
        post.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('posts', '00000000'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_author), # this will run the method above
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='post',
            name='author',
            field=models.ForeignKeyField...,
        ),

    ]
```

check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) for a more detailed explanation of how this works

Comment: You _need_ to use `apps.get_model()` to get at the model class; if you import it directly, you may get a model that does not correspond to the database at the time of migration.