# How can I fix this issue: Provide a one-off default now?

Tags: django, django-models

When I run `makemigrations` I get this error:

```
You are trying to add the field 'post_date' with 'auto_now_add=True' to user asking without a default; the database needs something
 to populate existing rows.

 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

In this code I try to set the date field and I find this error. When I do a search about this issue I find that I need to set the default and I set:

```
from django.utils import timezone
post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, default=timezone.now())
```

When I set `default` I get this error:

```
WARNINGS:
community.UserAsking.post_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
        HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If y
ou want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`
```

How can I skip this issue and migrate successfully?

`models.py`:

```
class UserAsking(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, help_text='Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person')
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, help_text='Include all the information someone would need to answer your question')
    field = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICE, default='Technology', help_text='Add the field to describe what your question is about')
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify a models who's already migrated in Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191615/how-to-modify-a-models-whos-already-migrated-in-database)

Comment: no, i can't make migrate because this error. do you read the post??

Comment: read the accepted answer. It demonstrates how to get rid of the issue

Comment: choose option 1 and type **`timezone.now`** and hit enter

Comment: yes, it wants me to set default and when i set the default I get a new error please read the whole post

Comment: use **`timezone.now`** (without paranthesis) not `timezone.now()`

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying that since you now want to have a default value for date field, you then need to provide on for the records that are already stored in DB.

First what you need to do is to change this:

```
models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, default=timezone.now())
```

to this:

```
models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Next - do as Arakkal Abu adviced:

> choose option 1 and type timezone.now and hit enter

Note: you do not need to call method like `now()` insead just use `now` (without parentheses)

Comment: I get a new error: **ERRORS:
community.UserAsking.post_date: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of
these options may be present.**

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin yes, sorry, you do not need to define `default` attribute since you already defined `auto_now_add`. I edited answer.

Comment: if i remove default I'll get the error that i should add a default. so, in this case, what is the default can i give

Comment: If you facing this next error during migration - type `use timezone.now` as default or just set a default value like `2020-02-17`

Comment: the same error that i mentioned above in comment has been raised again. at this moment I'll try by removing the database and try migrating again

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```py
    DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
date=DateField(default=timezone.now)
date=DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

one of them can be the solution

Answer (score -1):

Try:
about_title = models.Charfield(max_length, default=“about”)

This worked for me.