# Migrate From An IntegerField With Choices To A CharField

Tags: python, django

In Django I have a model with the following IntegerField.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Male'),
    (1, 'Female'),
)
gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

I would like to altar this model to become a CharField using the choices.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ("MALE", 'Male'),
    ("FEMALE", 'Female'),
    ("NA", 'Id Rather Not Say'),
)
gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=10)
```

If I were to do this by running `makemigrations` and `migrate` I would lose the existing data in the database.

How would I make this (and similar) migrations without losing the existing data in the database?

Ideally I would do this in the migration itself that way it will run on the production server the second we use the `migrate` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a data migration (as I recently outlined in this answer: [How to modify a models who's already migrated in Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191615/how-to-modify-a-models-whos-already-migrated-in-database/60192545#60192545)), but the steps are:

- rename `gender` to `gender_integer` (or similar); make a migration out of that
- add the new `gender` field; make a migration out of that
- create a data migration to map `gender_integer`'s content to `gender` (see the link above)
- remove `gender_integer`; make a migration out of that.

Comment: I really like this answer. One question though, do you think it would be too much of an issue to keep everything in one migration and just use multiple operations?

Comment: For databases where you can't mix schema editing and data editing one transaction (looking at you, MySQL), you should keep them separate.

Comment: I gotcha, that makes sense. I hadn't realized that django treats each migration as a single transaction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can store your old field and add new field your model with new choices. After that you can run standalone code and map your old data to new field.

Answer (score 0):

Migration 1: make a char field like gender_tmp, migrate all the data to it

Migration 2: remove gender and rename gender_tmp to gender